# How do i time three algorithms using timeit?

Tags: python

im trying to time these 3 algorithms using the same array so i can compare their speeds.

```
test= [5,4,7,9,2,3,6]

def insertionSort(array):
    arrayI= []
    arrayI = array.copy()

    for i in range(1,len(arrayI)):
        valor = arrayI[i]
        posicao = i

        while posicao>0 and arrayI[posicao-1] > valor:
            arrayI[posicao]=arrayI[posicao-1]
            posicao=posicao-1
            arrayI[posicao]=valor
    return arrayI
    

def selectSort(array):
    arrayS=[]
    arrayS=array.copy()
    lennumeros = range(0,len(arrayS)-1)
    

    for x in lennumeros:
        num_min = x

        for y in range(x+1,len(arrayS)):
            if arrayS[y] < arrayS[num_min]:
                num_min = y 
        if num_min != x:     
            arrayS[x], arrayS[num_min] = arrayS[num_min], arrayS[x] 
    return arrayS

def bubbleSort(array):
    arrayB=[]
    arrayB=array.copy()
   
    n = len(arrayB) 

    for i in range(n-1): 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arrayB[j] > arrayB[j+1] : 
                 arrayB[j], arrayB[j+1] = arrayB[j+1], arrayB[j]
    return arrayB
```

But i can´t seem to find my way using the timeit function.

Ive tried doing this:

```
print(timeit.timeit(insertionSort(test),number=10000000))
```

And variations of it, but ive had no success so far.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check the time at the start of your function and at the beginning.

```
import time

test= [5,4,7,9,2,3,6]

def insertionSort(array):
    arrayI= []
    arrayI = array.copy()

    for i in range(1,len(arrayI)):
        valor = arrayI[i]
        posicao = i

        while posicao>0 and arrayI[posicao-1] > valor:
            arrayI[posicao]=arrayI[posicao-1]
            posicao=posicao-1
            arrayI[posicao]=valor
    return arrayI
    

def selectSort(array):
    arrayS=[]
    arrayS=array.copy()
    lennumeros = range(0,len(arrayS)-1)
    

    for x in lennumeros:
        num_min = x

        for y in range(x+1,len(arrayS)):
            if arrayS[y] < arrayS[num_min]:
                num_min = y 
        if num_min != x:     
            arrayS[x], arrayS[num_min] = arrayS[num_min], arrayS[x] 
    return arrayS

def bubbleSort(array):
    arrayB=[]
    arrayB=array.copy()
   
    n = len(arrayB) 

    for i in range(n-1): 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arrayB[j] > arrayB[j+1] : 
                 arrayB[j], arrayB[j+1] = arrayB[j+1], arrayB[j]
    return arrayB

nrep = 10000000

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(nrep):
    insertionSort(test)
totalI = time.time() - start_time

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(nrep):
    selectSort(test)
totalS = time.time() - start_time

start_time = time.time()
for _ in range(nrep):
    bubbleSort(test)
totalB = time.time() - start_time

print(f"insertionSort(): {round(totalI,2)} seconds")
print(f"selectSort(): {round(totalS,2)} seconds")
print(f"bubbleSort(): {round(totalB,2)} seconds")

#insertionSort(): 45.1 seconds
#selectSort(): 63.24 seconds
#bubbleSort(): 78.59 seconds
```

Comment: It  always tells me it took 0.0 time to run?

Comment: I've edited it so it includes the whole code, including the output I got.

Comment: Thank you! Would you say its normal for an array with something like 2-8 elements to show up as 0.0 seconds?

Comment: If you would run the code once, then 0.0 seconds is perfectly normal. However, if you run the code say 100,000 times, then no. Also note, you can also use the built-in functions sorted() or list.sort(), which are about 20 times faster than your fastest methoded (insertionSort())

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the function inside a lambda

```py
test = [5, 4, 7, 9, 2, 3, 6]
number = 10_000_000
for sorter in (insertionSort, selectSort, bubbleSort):
    print(sorter.__name__, timeit(lambda: sorter(test), number=number))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
insertionSort 66.67362030000001
selectSort 70.8069464
bubbleSort 87.19788589999999
```